# How to provide a list of arguments to cookiecutter?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cookiecutter

I am trying to build a cookiecutter template for a terraform repository.
The repo is used to create buckets. I would like to add a "buckets" argument, where bucket is a list.
I tried something like this in the cookiecutter.json.

```
{
    "buckets": ["bucket_1", "bucket_2", "bucket_3"],
    "arg2": value
}
```

but it appears that doing this just asks if you want to pick bucket_1/2 or 3. I would actually to allow creating 1 bucket or several and not just pick an option in that list. Is it something feasible with cookiecutter ?